# ServiceWorkers - how to compare between fetch response and cached asset

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I have a service worker that caches my app's static resources.

In one of my use-cases, I need to fetch an asset from the network and also fetch the corresponding cached asset from the cache, then only if their content differs I need to store the new asset in the cache and do additional processing on it. For different reasons it is crucial for me to know if that asset has changed.

Is it possible to do something like that using the Response interface of the fetch API?

The blob() or text() functions implemented under Response.Body interface sound relevant https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response

But before starting experimentation I would to have some clue about my options and any caveats in such approach.

One more thought re this - isn't there a way to get from the server a 304 response if the file has not changed since cached?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't experimented with 304 responses in Service Workers, but that's a great way to start.

`etag` response headers would also indicate changes. Your server must authorize your application to view the `etag` header by sending the required CORS header: `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: etag`.  Otherwise `response.headers.get('etag')` returns `null`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag

As an example, Nginx seems to generate weak etag values from last modified time and content length ([more info](https://serverfault.com/questions/690341/algorithm-behind-nginx-etag-generation)). Therefore, if changes occurred that kept the document the same length (i.e. CSS changed from `width: 10px` to `width: 20px`, modified time would be the only indicator of change.  Comparing differences with the actual content could be done with string comparison functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
caches.open('cache-and-update-v1.1.4').then(function (cache) {
    cache.match('/').then(m => m.text()).then(b=>{
        fetch('/').then(res=>res.text()).then(e => console.log(b.localeCompare(e)))
    })
})
```

Answer (score -1):

I ended up comparing the last-modified header of the network response and the cached response, as answered by cøder one could (or should) use the etag header.

Regarding the 304 - this is obfuscated by the browser's cache and the service worker just gets a 200. Moreover, even if you could get that info it won't be reliable cause the asset might have been recached since inserted to the service worker's cache.

As mentioned in the question, at some scenarios I still need to compare the actual contents of that asset, in which case I use the `text()` method on the response to get a promise to the actual content. Be sure to clone the response before consuming it if you have further need of it.